# El Capitan’s full screen split view via CLI?

Tags: macos, split-view

El Capitan introduced [a new split screen mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p8AsQhaVKI&feature=youtu.be&t=13m7s). Is there a way to enter it via CLI?

I’m guessing that if there is a way to do this, it’ll be via AppleScript (to get `active window`, and whatnot), but the language isn’t really important, as long as it can be done via CLI.

Comment: Why do you need to do it via CLI?

Comment: Because it means I can script it with tools. Not sure what you want to know with that question, though, this isn’t an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I want to do it because I want to do that thing specifically, the “why” isn’t that relevant, in this case.